# Best way to handle ajax navigation within a single page for JQM

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I am converting a traditional website to jqm using the single page model. However, there are a couple pages that have tabs that I would like to:

1. Display the data for the tab within the same page when the tab is clicked
2. Add the tab to history.

Example of what I want to do: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/demo.html

What is the best way to do this using jqm? Listening to hashchange as I did with the traditional website doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the history to change, you could check out [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) It's a pretty neat tool that works with the History API in HTML5 if it's available, but can work quite well with HTML4 (though I have no experience in that regard)

EDIT: And of course you can always just call a function to update the content of the data field according to the tab being pressed :) Forgot to mention that aspect before. If you need some guidance on this, feel free to ask, but I figure you've got that part under control